# Laravel 4 - PHP tag is prefixed in artisan console and rendered pages

Tags: php, laravel, console, vagrant, laravel-artisan

I have this weird issue with my project. When I'm using artisan command e.g.:

```
php artisan -v
<?phpLaravel Framework version 4.2.22
```

Also when I inspect page there is

```
<?php<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
```

I can't figure out from where are `<?php` tags from, I checked whole project.
I am using vagrant for local development, other projects with L4 works just fine.

This bothers me a lot, I can't even call ajax to get proper response without these tags. Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in `app/start/local.php`

Someone changed

```
<?php

//
```

to

```
<?php
```

and this caused the issues.

Additional info: Removing file or just adding new line will fix the problem (or just leave it as it was before)

Comment: So I guess that my answer helped you or it solved the issue. Cheers.

Comment: Your suggestion was first thing that come to my mind, when issue shows up. But thank you anyway for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to look for all that string in all your App files. It sounds like you have that string duplicated. It could be at the beginning of your file or anywhere. From the first output you posted it looks like the string is located in one of the Laravel files (maybe a configuration file?). This is a tedious task but is the only solution for this kind of errors.